# (Putnam) Let $f:[1,3] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $-1 \leq f(x) \leq 1 $ for all x and

Tags: calculus, contest-math, integral-inequality

The following is a Putnam math competition problem:

> Let $f:[1,3] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $-1 \leq f(x) \leq 1 $ for all x and $ \int_{1}^{3}f(x)dx = 0 $. What is the max value of $\int_{1}^{3} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx$ ?

What I did:

$$\int_{1}^{3} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx \leq \int_{1}^{3} \frac1x dx = \log(3) $$

if we define $g(x) = f(x) + 1$ then $0\leq g(x) \leq 2$ and:

$$\int_{1}^{3}g(x)dx = 2$$
$$\int_{1}^{3}\frac{f(x)}xdx = \int_{1}^{3} \frac{g(x)-1}{x}dx = \frac{\int_{1}^{3}g(x)dx}{c} - \log(3)$$

with $c \in (1,3)$ so the max value is on the interval $[\frac23 - \log(3), \log(3)]$

I thought about using $g_n(x) = f(x) + x^{n}$ and try to make a better lower bound, but I don't think this will help much to find the exact maximum value

Comment: What happens if you consider $f(x)=1$ for $1\le x\le2$, and $f(x)=-1$ for $2\le x\le 3$?

Comment: you get one particular case, an interisting one thou, this would give a value of $2\log(2) - \log(3)$ to the integral of $\frac f x$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Intuitively speaking,** you are putting "mass" along the line $[1,3]$ such that the total mass is zero, and the density at any point must only be between $1$ and $-1$. Since you are trying to maximize the value of $\int_1^3 f(x) / x \; dx$, mass closer to $1$ is weighted higher and mass closer to $3$ is weighted lower. So you should put as much mass as possible close to $1$, which means the optimal function will be $1$ on the interval $[1,2]$ and $-1$ on the interval $[2,3]$.

**Rigorous argument:** Based on the above intuition, let
$$
g(x) := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } 1 \le x \le 2 \\ -1 & \text{if } 2 \le x \le 3 \end{cases}
$$
We wish to show that for any $f : [1,3] \to [-1,1]$ with integral $0$, $\int_1^3 f(x) / x \; dx \le \int_1^3 g(x) / x \; dx$. To prove this, take the difference :
\begin{align*}
\int_1^3 \frac{g(x)}{x} \; dx - \int_1^3 \frac{f(x)}{x} \; dx
&= \int_1^3 \frac{g(x) - f(x)}{x} \; dx \\
&= \int_1^2 \frac{g(x) - f(x)}{x} \; dx
+ \int_2^3 \frac{g(x) - f(x)}{x} \; dx \\
&= \int_1^2 \frac{1 - f(x)}{x} \; dx
+ \int_2^3 \frac{-1 - f(x)}{x} \; dx \\
&= \int_1^2 \frac{1 - f(x)}{x} \; dx
- \int_2^3 \frac{1 + f(x)}{x} \; dx \\
&\ge \int_1^2 \frac{1 - f(x)}{2} \; dx
- \int_2^3 \frac{1 + f(x)}{2} \; dx \text{ (both integrands were positive)}\\
&= \frac12\left[1 - \int_1^2 f(x) \; dx \right]
- \frac12 \left[1 + \int_2^3 f(x) \; dx \right] \\
&= 0 - \int_1^3 f(x) \; dx \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Is it possible to solve this using Lebesgue integration? For example, given an f, can you "rearrange" it so that it is decreasing? Or would it suffice to consider a Riemann partition of $\int f(x)dx$ and the same partition of $\int \frac{f(x)}{x} dx$?

Comment: @Akababa That could be another good approach. I think something like that could work using either the Lebesgue or Riemann integral.

Comment: And then show compactness of the set of possible f and continuity of the map $f\mapsto \int_1^3 \frac{f(x)}{x}dx$, and since every f which is not non-increasing is an interior point then the supremum must be a non-increasing function? (sorry can't edit comments after 5 min)

Comment: @Akababa Seems reasonable, why don't you try to write a solution?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try but not sure if I can make it rigorous.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E=[1,3]$. Assume $f:E\to[0,2]$ is Riemann integrable with $\int_E f=1$. Let $P_n$ be the partition $1,1+\frac1{2n},...,3$ of $E$, then the upper Darboux sum for $f$ is:
$$U(f,P_n)=\sum_i b_i\frac1{2n}\geq \int_E f(x)dx=1$$
Then
$$\sum_i \frac{b_i}{1+\frac i{2n}}\frac1{2n}\geq\sum_i (\sup_{t\in [1+\frac i{2n},1+\frac{i+1}{2n}]}\frac{f(t)}t)\frac1{2n}=U(\frac{f(x)}{x},P_n)\geq\int_E\frac{f(x)}xdx$$
Suppose $U(f,P_n)=1+\epsilon$. Then
$$\sum_i \frac{b_i}{1+\frac i{2n}}\frac1{2n}$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{b_i}{2n+i}+\sum_{i=n}^{2n-1} \frac{b_i}{2n+i}$$
$$=\sum_{i=n}^{2n-1} \frac{b_i}{2n+i}-(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{2-b_i}{2n+i})+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{2}{2n+i}$$
$$\leq \sum_{i=n}^{2n-1} \frac{b_i}{2n}-(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{2-b_i}{2n})+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{2}{2n+i}$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{2n-1} \frac{b_i}{2n}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{2}{2n}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{2}{2n+i}$$
$$=(1+\epsilon)-1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{2}{2n+i}$$
$$=\epsilon+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{2}{1+\frac i{2n}}\frac1{2n}$$
$$=\epsilon+U(\frac{g(x)}x,P_n)$$
where $g(x) = \begin{cases} 2 & \text{if } 1 \le x \le 2 \\ 0 & \text{if } 2 \le x \le 3 \end{cases}$

Therefore
$$\int_E\frac{f(x)}xdx\leq U(\frac{g(x)}x,P_n)+\epsilon$$
When $n\to\infty$, we get $\epsilon\to0$ and the RHS becomes
$$\int_E \frac{g(x)}xdx=\int_1^2 \frac2xdx=\log4$$
Conversely, $g$ satisfies the conditions of $f$ so the maximum is attainable.
Transforming back to the original range, the maximum is 
$$\int_1^3 \frac{g(x)-1}xdx=\log4-\log3$$